# Play 2.5 scala import class with Dependency Injection

Tags: scala, object, import, playframework, dependency-injection

I have a class **Api** with Dependency Injection, with a function that use this injection:

```
class Api @Inject()(userRepo: UserRepo) extends Controller {
  def user(email: String) ={
    userRepo.getUser(email).map( .... )
  }
}
```

And an object **FlashSession** in the same package - I am using it in a lot of others files. 
I want to use the function **user** into my obj **FlashSession**.

```
object FlashSession { 
  def test = ... Api.user("test@gmail.com") .... 
}
```

But I can not import the **Api** class because it is a class and not an object, and I can not put this function into the compagnon object because it needs DI.

What is best way to deal with it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this `Api` class inside `FlashSession`

```
object FlashSession {
   def test = new Api(new UserRepo()).user(...)
}
```

or

```
object FlashSession {
   def test(userRepo: UserRepo) = new Api(userRepo).user(...)
}
```

But this is probably not what you really want. You should not use global companion objects with DI, especially for database data manipulation.

Comment: Thank you, but effectively, it is not exactly what I wanted, because I use the Api class as controller. But I can adapte your answer, and do something with it.
What do you mean by "not use global companion objects with DI" ? It means that your solution is not very good, right?

Comment: Yes, using constructor DI requires some adaptation in code. You simply should rather pass needed classes through constructor then using Global objects. @bruce-lowe answer below shows good insight of this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Api.user("email") since Api is a class and not an object. In java its like calling a a non-static method from a static method. Theoretically you could have more than 1 instance of Api, or even no instances of Api.  Therefore it makes no sense to use the class Api in the object FlashSession.

If you change Flash to a class and inject the Api class it will work better:

```
class FlashSession @Inject()(api: Api) { 
  def test = ... api.user("test@gmail.com") .... 
}
```

You will then need to inject FlashSession into all the classes that use it.

You may find new developers will make everything an object since its easiest, and not do any DI (dependency injection).  In order to allow more effective testing with things like mocks, they evolve into using DI.  However mixing and matching classes with DI, and objects doesn't work well.

Comment: I asked this question to know if there is a "beautiful" code for achieve want I want. Apparently not... So I will probably forget about it, and do it in an other way, that does not create such a mess. 
But thank you for your answer!